# How can I include a Picker as a MenuItem in .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

Is it possible to add a dropdown Picker into a MAUI Flyout? I have a requirement to make a global choice available easily to all Pages. I know I could create a Settings Page, but it would be easier for the users to do it in the menu.

I have inserted the Picker sample code into a MenuItem, but am getting this error:

> XLS0502   The type 'MenuItem' does not support direct content.

Is there some other way to do this, or is cross-platform compatibility somehow limiting our ability here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="SAE.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SAE.MVVM.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"
    Shell.FlyoutBackground="DarkGray">

    <FlyoutItem Title="Items" Icon="building_regular.png">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Items}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>

    <MenuItem Text="Color">
            <Picker Title="Color"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Margin="10, 0"
                SelectedIndexChanged="OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged">
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>Aqua</x:String>
                    <x:String>Black</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue</x:String>
                    <x:String>Fuchsia</x:String>
                    <x:String>Gray</x:String>
                    <x:String>Green</x:String>
                    <x:String>Lime</x:String>
                    <x:String>Maroon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Navy</x:String>
                    <x:String>Olive</x:String>
                    <x:String>Purple</x:String>
                    <x:String>Red</x:String>
                    <x:String>Silver</x:String>
                    <x:String>Teal</x:String>
                    <x:String>White</x:String>
                    <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
                </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
    </MenuItem>


</Shell>
```

Comment: I don’t think a MenuItem was designed to include any content, as the error message says.

Comment: I have just edited the question to expand the scope.

Comment: You could launch a modal page containing the picker

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ColorPage` to set the color and create a global variable to store the selected color, then you can access the global variable from other pages in your app .

You can refer to the following code:

1.define a `ColorPage` in `AppShell.xaml`

2.ColorPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ColorPage : ContentPage 
{
    //create a global variable here

    public static string CHOOSEDCOLOR = "";
      public ColorPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

        if (selectedIndex != -1)
        {
            CHOOSEDCOLOR = (string)picker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex];
            mColorLabel.Text = CHOOSEDCOLOR;
        }
    }
}
```

3.The code of `ColorPage.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp925.ColorPage"
             Title="ColorPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text=""
            x:Name="mColorLabel"
            VerticalOptions="Start" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Picker Title="Please choose color"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Margin="20"
                SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_SelectedIndexChanged">

            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Aqua</x:String>
                    <x:String>Black</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue</x:String>
                    <x:String>Fuchsia</x:String>
                    <x:String>Gray</x:String>
                    <x:String>Green</x:String>
                    <x:String>Lime</x:String>
                    <x:String>Maroon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Navy</x:String>
                    <x:String>Olive</x:String>
                    <x:String>Purple</x:String>
                    <x:String>Red</x:String>
                    <x:String>Silver</x:String>
                    <x:String>Teal</x:String>
                    <x:String>White</x:String>
                    <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
           
        </Picker>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

4.Then you can access the global variable `CHOOSEDCOLOR`  in other pages as follows:

```
     string color = ColorPage.CHOOSEDCOLOR;
```

Comment: all the question is focused on adding a content (view = Picker) to `MenuItem`, while i don't see how your suggested solution answers this concern

Comment: Although I appreciate the time you took to reply to my question, as Cfun points out it's not actually addressing the use case I need.

Comment: As the error shows that `The type 'MenuItem' does not support direct content.` so I posted a workaround.